# What is the chosen number of the person who announced an average of 6?

Tags: average, means

[image: Circle of people]
Ten people stand in a circle. Each chooses a number and tells the person to their left and right. Each person averages the two numbers they heard and they go in a circle announcing the average of their numbers which are recorded in this “circle.” What number did the person who had an average of 6 choose?

Although this problem can be solved with a system, is there any logical way to find the answer without a calculator and minimal work? I’ve been trying to figure the answer out and apparently there is an ‘elegant’ solution, but I don’t know what it is.

Thanks.!

Edit: here’s the work if I solved the problem as a system
[variables per person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCfWm.jpg)[image: system itself]

Comment: How are the numbers chosen?...

Comment: The numbers weren’t chosen based on anything.

Comment: Sorry, I now realize that the image is showing the averages that each person announces.

Comment: Well if they all choose 6, everybody will announce an average of 6, while if they all choose 1, no-one will. Your question needs to supply more detail.

Comment: @RobArthan: See angryavian's comment above.

Comment: Rob, unfortunately this is all the information I have to work with

Comment: One simplification is to note that you only care about the equations involving $A$, $C$, $E$, $G$, and $I$ (using your notation) and you can ignore the rest.

Comment: That’s actually a good idea, but I don’t know where to go from there

Comment: @joriki: I don't see how angryavian's comment addresses my comment.

Comment: @RobArthan because he provided all of the averages, not the values.

Comment: If the original question is about the specific example in the graphic, then the OP should say so. I am voting to close this question as unclear (it's also  deeply uninteresting).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question was also asked [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/27580/10615), where many solutions are given. Here is mine.

---

Let $g_n$ be the number the $n$th person picked, so that $(g_{n-1}+g_{n+1})/2=n$ for $1\le n\le 10$ (where indices wrap around the circle, so $g_0=g_{10})$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
g_6 
&= (g_6-g_4)/2 + (g_6+g_4)/2\\
&= (g_6+(g_8-g_8)+(-g_{10}+g_{10})+(g_2-g_2)-g_4)/2 + (g_6+g_4)/2\\
&= (g_6+g_8)/2 -(g_8+g_{10})/2+(g_{10}+g_2)/2-(g_2+g_4)/2+(g_6+g_4)/2\\
&= 7-9+1-3+5=\boxed{1}
\end{align}
$$

---

The insight that leads to this proof is that in the circular arrangement $(g_2,g_4,g_6,g_8,g_{10})$, you know what the sum of any two adjacent numbers are. You can tile this circle with "dominos" in two ways; one where every number is covered once except for $g_6$ which is covered twice, and one where every number is covered once except for $g_6$ which is uncovered. Subtracting these two tilings gives you the value of $g_6$.

Comment: Among the answers you link to, I prefer the one that uses symmetry to deduce that the number between the averages $1$ and $9$ must be $5$, from which the result quickly follows.

Comment: Thanks for adding the "moral" -- the proof seemed mechanical without that; now it's clear that it follows a nice idea.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a nice fact: we can totally ignore considering what any person who announced an odd number said. Why? Because no odd number person is 2 places away from an even number person, so they won't affect each other in the computation of averages anywhere.

Denote the person who said 2 as A, 4, as B, 6 as C, 8 as D, and 10 as E

So,

\begin{align}
A+E = 2\\
B+A = 6\\
C+B = 10\\
D+C = 14\\
E+D = 18
\end{align}

After some algebra, you get  $A = -3, B= 9, C= 1, D= 13, E= 5$. So the answer is $\color{red}{1}$.

Answer (score 1):

First, the sum of the numbers of the people who announced even numbers is $1+3+5+7+9=25$  The naive approach is to let the person who announced $2$ have the number $a$, the person who announced $4$ have the number $b$ and so on.  We  want $c$ and get 
$$a+b=6\\b+c=10\\c+d=14\\d+e=18\\a+e=2\\e=2-a\\d-a=16\\b+d=22\\b-c=8\\c=1\\b=9\\d=13\\a=-3\\e=5$$
where we could have stopped after the $c=1$ line but I did the rest to check.  It is only five lines after writing the given equations, each of which is only a couple additions or subtractions.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that the odd and even slots are uncoupled; the even averages only depend on the numbers chosen by the people announcing odd averages and vice versa. Thus, we only need to consider the announced averages $1,3,5,7,9$ to find the number chosen by the person announcing $6$.

Second, we can form [this inverse](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse%20of%20%7B%7B1,1,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,1,1,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,1,1,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,1,1%7D,%7B1,0,0,0,1%7D%7D&dataset=) to get an idea how to invert the averaging operation: To find the number chosen between two averages, add them, subtract their neighbours and add their neighbour. This yields $-3,9,1,13,5$, which can readily be checked to yield the above averages, so the number chosen by the person who announced $6$ is $1$.